# Vuejs String formatting not working correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron, vue-component, vuex

Hi am trying to style a div dynamically in VueJs.But facing this problem that the `this.currentProgressLevel` is not applied to the width property inside the currentStyle object.I am attaching the screenshot of code i am using. The width property is not working when i use `${this.currentProgressLevel *75}px` Why it might not be working?When i change the `this.currentProgressLevel` with 0.33 **manually** it works but then it will be hardcoded, why the value is not taken from the data variable `currentProgressLevel`? Below is the code i am using:

In script :

```
data(){
return{
currentProgressLevel:.33,
currentStyle:{
width: ${this.currentProgressLevel *75}px ,
height:‘6px’,
background:‘green’
}
}}
```

[image: Screenshot of Code i am using]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn `currentStyle` into `computed` like this:

```
computed: {
  currentStyle () {
    return {
      width: `${this.currentProgressLevel *75}px`,
      height:‘6px’,
      background:‘green’
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reactive data, you should move 'currentStyle' to computed. in this case, you just catch the initial value of 'currentProgressLevel'.

```
computed:{
  currentStyle(){
    return {
      width: ${this.currentProgressLevel *75}px ,
      height:‘6px’,
      background:‘green’
    }
  }
}
```